# How can I change the default HTML escaping function in React Components?

Tags: reactjs

I would like to substitute the default escaping function (escapes everything) with a function that matches my company's policy (white listed a, ul, ol, etc). How do I replace the built-in escape function with my own?

I can use this, but it's kind of annoying to use throughout the app, since almost all data falls under our company-wide policy:

```
<div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{__html: myEscapeFunc(data)}} />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a new React component and call it "AllowedHtml" where you can put all the functionality and pass data regularly without the akward `{{__html:` prefix

```
<AllowedHtml html={data}/>
```